An unexplained flurry of upvotes
This five-year-old answer of mine has suddenly received 18 votes in a single day (so far). I'm really curious -- how can I find out why? It's not linked to by any Stack Exchange posts that I can find. Is this a hopeless quest?

Note that a new contributor answered that question in the last day and edited it 46 times (as of now)

It's nice to see a good, thorough answer like that rack up votes. My highest voted answer was a minor notation question that got on the HNQ list.

It really is a very good answer. You had me at three sentences in.

There is a new answer added to that question 11 hours ago. This bumped the post into the top page. More importantly, the answer-er had done LOTS of edits during the past several hours, hence the said post must be at the top page for a very long period of time

Wow, that's a lot of edits. Plus, it's an intriguing question, so people are going to read the already-highly-voted answers.
